Does SSAS have project parameters like SSIS?
I'm learning SSAS.  In SSIS, I can create project parameters that allow me to pass in things like the SQL Server name.  With that I can run the same SSIS project against different servers simply by passing in a different server name.
Does SSAS have anything like this?  How do you develop a SSAS project against a development server then deploy that project to UAT and Production servers?  ThankS!
